# Atom language-jenkins plugin to support Jenkinsfile name with wildcard?

Tags: javascript, json, atom-editor, cson

The Atom editor plugin [language-jenkins](https://atom.io/packages/language-jenkinsfile) highlights the syntax for `Jenkinsfile`.

However, my Jenkinsfiles are not always named `Jenkinsfile`, but usually have extension: `Jenkinsfile-x86`, `Jenkinsfile-arm`, `Jenkinsfile-test`, etc.

How would I need to modify the Atom plugin [source code](https://github.com/b4nst/language-jenkinsfile/blob/master/grammars/jenkinsfile.cson) in order to support any file name starting with `Jenkinsfile*`?

This poor man's solution works, but...:

```
'fileTypes': [
  'Jenkinsfile',
  'Jenkinsfile-x86',
  'Jenkinsfile-arm',
  'Jenkinsfile-test'
]
```

Comment: Not a solution, but you should be aware that Atom will no longer be developed after 2022: https://techcrunch.com/2022/06/08/github-sunsets-atom-the-software-dev-environment-it-launched-in-2011/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9kdWNrZHVja2dvLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAAuFnD6rhDei6ewkymY8DjpFWPL9SEzXJezXLUZnKDxu-Fxx7k_MJ_vpqOTypo1ZlBlm_ec1An13fUMJNrpFJHErYNYrj7f-TBxz-Yz0ue4kLQbAvlyte90HdLlWxcbSC3VkLvxoIq1KiHUGXK8ky99jbs7BSycw5n-sdkH4mjNv .

Comment: @Mo3bius Indeed, that was the solution. (Switched to VSCode.) Thanks. :-)